# accessing external speakers using assembly

Tags: audio, assembly, x86-16, speaker, port-number

I want to write a piece of assembly code that generates sounds with different frequencies with  access to external speakers (not the internal PC speaker). Can I do such a thing using assembly 8086? If so, where can I get the port number of my external speakers (let's say the built-in laptop speakers)?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can.  What's your OS?

Comment: Windows has a driver for that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536829(v=vs.85).aspx .  This is a portable way of doing it.  Also if you go into "device manager" you can locate any piece of hardware and it's port addresses.  Only drivers have access to hardware.

Comment: Also using assembly may not necessarily improve performance as the real gains come from your cpu and sound card combo.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that what you're trying to do relies on legacy hardware - e.g. PC AT, and obviously isn't going to work on anything less than 20 years old or so!

Comment: I'm supposed to do a project (That is generating sounds and playing WAV files) on intel 8086 chip. Now I'm kinda puzzled.

Comment: On 8086? Is it Windows 1 then?

Comment: :)) It's just a project. I code assembly in Emu8086.